# Error Creating iPhone ad hoc distribution

Tags: iphone, adhoc, entitlements

I'm trying to do an ad hoc distribution of my iPhone app to some beta testers. I created the certs, device IDs, provisioning profiles, etc. and followed the instructions on Apple's site regarding how to incorporate them into the build/distribution. When I copy the provisioning profile and app to iTunes and try to sync, I get the following message:

The application "XYZ" was not installed on the iPhone "Eric's iPhone" because the entitlements are not valid.

It seems like everyone else that runs into this problem solves it by adding the Entitlements.plist file to the build configuration. The thing is, I've created (and edited) that file correctly. I see it and the provisioning profile in the built app.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Regards,
Eric

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558642/entitlements-are-not-valid

Answer (score 0):

Did you go into the build settings for the AdHoc configuration and make sure the Code Signing Entitlements setting is set to point to your Entitlements.plist file?