# How to get this app into my iPhone (Ad Hoc)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an iPhone app I have developed that I want to have some Ad Hoc testers use.  I have a file "xx.ipa" and a "xx.mobileprovision" in a directory on my iMac, which has been uploaded to a private website.

It was built with Xcode, I have all of the provisioning profiles downloaded (Dev, Dist and Ad Hoc).

My tester tells me that it won't load, so I want to load it on my iPhone (it is one of the "devices", his iPhone is the other), so I can see what is wrong and fix it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop both of those files onto iTunes and sync. As long as the device syncing is listed in the provisioning profile, there should be no issues.

If you are trying to test the Ad Hoc installation, just do the same. I would remove any build installed by Xcode during development though.

Comment: Thanks, that worked... however, I'm getting the following error:

"app" was not installed on "device" because the entitlements are not valid.

What does that mean?  (you can tell I'm new at this... sorry for the lame questions)

Comment: You need to add an `Entitlements.plist`, then add a `TRUE` bool entry to **get-task-allow**.

Comment: Nope... still getting the same error... I added "get-task-allow" and checked the checkbox (there is no TRUE), so I assumed checking the checkbox would to it.

Comment: Checking the Checkbox and TRUE are the same values ;-P. Check out this SO question on Ad Hoc, this should help you with that issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558642/entitlements-are-not-valid

Comment: I've checked and re-checked... nothing works... any other ideas?

Comment: Make sure you clean your builds, I would even delete the build directory.

Comment: on recent (4.1, 4.2) sdks there is no longer a "get-task-allow" checkbox in the Entitlements.plist, so there's nothing to forget to check (or uncheck, I think that's what you had to do before).

Comment: @Spokane-Dude You don't run Xcode4? Do you? I had the entitlements problem 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @Bogatyr creating an Entitlements.plist file is blank anyway. You manually add the `get-task-allow` option.

Comment: @WrightsCS: in 3.x sdks, you had to create the Entitlements.plist file, open it, and uncheck the get-task-allow box.   In 4.x sdks, you simply create the file and you're done with it.   I opened the file just to look in to it because I was used to having to uncheck the get-task-allow box, and there was no such box, so telling people to uncheck that box is out of date.

Comment: and I don't even have an Entitlements.plist file. And I just installed the app via adhoc. BTW: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1710.html

Comment: fluchtpunkt... no, I'm running Xcode 3.2.5... I have deleted ALL of my provisioning profiles, re-created them, and STILL can't get past this... it works in Debug|Simulator, but not on the device (it used to work on the device before I had these problems with Ad Hoc).

Comment: found the problem!  Indeed, you need the "get-task-allow", but it has to be UNCHECKED... did that and it works like a champ!

Thanks everybody for your time and help!