# iphone app crashes: work fine in development but when downloaded from itunes it crashes

Tags: iphone, web-services, itunes, iphone-sdk-4.1, crash

I developed one application, recently I launched it in the apple store.
When I download the application from the itunes and launch it, it crashes at the point it retrieving the data from the web service. It works absolutely fine if I install it from the sdk.

Please let me know what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!!

```
Crash Log

Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-03-02 18:15:46.353 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xc9220021
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33479466 0x33476000 + 13414
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a5ebb8 0x33a20000 + 256952
2   Foundation                      0x3363978e 0x33619000 + 133006
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a767d6 0x33a20000 + 354262
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a485b0 0x33a20000 + 165296
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47e54 0x33a20000 + 163412
6   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
7   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
8   GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 0x33b0a000 + 17572
9   GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 0x33b0a000 + 17744
10  UIKit                           0x32099322 0x32062000 + 226082
11  UIKit                           0x32096e8c 0x32062000 + 216716
12  Bagainfly                       0x000020de 0x1000 + 4318
13  Bagainfly                       0x00002074 0x1000 + 4212

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 0x33b5c000 + 186740
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 0x33b5c000 + 882436
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 0x33b5c000 + 881012
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 0x33b5c000 + 879512
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a 0x33b5c000 + 504394
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 0x30428000 + 749860
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
6   Foundation                      0x336465f6 0x33619000 + 185846
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 0x33619000 + 45458
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 0x33619000 + 16962
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8168c 0x33b5c000 + 153228
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a7f662 0x33a20000 + 390754
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba6c 0x33b5c000 + 457324
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8a06a 0x33b5c000 + 188522
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3375ca16 0x33748000 + 84502
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3374a88a 0x33748000 + 10378
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x33754ffa 0x33748000 + 53242
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x33760f40 0x33748000 + 102208
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x33774c9c 0x33748000 + 183452
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x33788dee 0x33748000 + 265710
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x33749de4 0x33748000 + 7652
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x33749f6a 0x33748000 + 8042
10  GMM                             0x330ff524 0x330fd000 + 9508
11  GMM                             0x330ff57c 0x330fd000 + 9596
12  GMM                             0x3313743e 0x330fd000 + 238654
13  MapKit                          0x31bf48ca 0x31be4000 + 67786
14  MapKit                          0x31bf480a 0x31be4000 + 67594
15  CoreFoundation                  0x33a767d6 0x33a20000 + 354262
16  CoreFoundation                  0x33a485b0 0x33a20000 + 165296
17  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47e54 0x33a20000 + 163412
18  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
19  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
20  MapKit                          0x31be8906 0x31be4000 + 18694
21  MapKit                          0x31be87ea 0x31be4000 + 18410
22  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
23  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd59f0 0x33b5c000 + 498160
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8a7ec 0x33b5c000 + 190444
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8a3d2 0x33b5c000 + 189394
3   QuartzCore                      0x3412e5dc 0x340f9000 + 218588
4   QuartzCore                      0x340fb01a 0x340f9000 + 8218
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d294 0x33b5c000 + 4756
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8b026 0x33b5c000 + 192550
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f258 0x33b5c000 + 12888
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347a5b8 0x33476000 + 17848
4   Foundation                      0x33630782 0x33619000 + 96130
5   Foundation                      0x336303f4 0x33619000 + 95220
6   Foundation                      0x3363007a 0x33619000 + 94330
7   MapKit                          0x31c10ef0 0x31be4000 + 184048
8   MapKit                          0x31c10e70 0x31be4000 + 183920
9   GMM                             0x33137d66 0x330fd000 + 240998
10  GMM                             0x330fe768 0x330fd000 + 5992
11  Foundation                      0x3364b806 0x33619000 + 206854
12  Foundation                      0x3364b788 0x33619000 + 206728
13  CFNetwork                       0x30ca747e 0x30c98000 + 62590
14  CFNetwork                       0x30c9c1f2 0x30c98000 + 16882
15  CFNetwork                       0x30c9c0e4 0x30c98000 + 16612
16  CFNetwork                       0x30c9c096 0x30c98000 + 16534
17  CFNetwork                       0x30c9c014 0x30c98000 + 16404
18  CFNetwork                       0x30c9bf92 0x30c98000 + 16274
19  CoreFoundation                  0x33a767d6 0x33a20000 + 354262
20  CoreFoundation                  0x33a485b0 0x33a20000 + 165296
21  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47e54 0x33a20000 + 163412
22  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
23  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
24  MapKit                          0x31bf327e 0x31be4000 + 62078
25  Foundation                      0x33624192 0x33619000 + 45458
26  Foundation                      0x3361d242 0x33619000 + 16962
27  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
28  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x001504a0    r1: 0x323738ef      r2: 0x303b83f2      r3: 0x0000004c
    r4: 0x33a59245    r5: 0xc9220021      r6: 0x3e4f4b74      r7: 0x2fdfec0c
    r8: 0x303b83f2    r9: 0x2fdfea50     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x0013971c
    ip: 0x3e4efab4    sp: 0x2fdfebec      lr: 0x31c10f53      pc: 0x33479466
  cpsr: 0x000f0030
```

Comment: how do you suppose somebody would answer your question? no crash log, no code, no info...

Answer (score 2):

When you say launched in AppleStore, do you mean from iTunes or do you mean it's been published by Apple already?

If you mean from iTunes and is an adhoc build have you checked your entitlements.plist?
[Another stackoverflow question about entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558642/entitlements-are-not-valid)

If it is actually approved and on AppStore you can take a look at the crash logs generated by using the technique here.

[How to get crash logs](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/55116-how-get-crash-logs-data-iphone-os-ios.html)

Another possibility is if you're connecting with a real device for the first time and have a slow or intermittent connection and you're using a synchronous launch you may find that the IOS system is killing your app as it's taking > 10 seconds to respond so it's assumed it's crashed.

Not sure if any of this will help as we could really do with more details on the crash. E.g. does it work 100% in simulator, does it work from launching in Xcode, is it an debug/release/adhoc/distribution build, have you tried NSLog messages to narrow down where it's crashing?

Comment: Thank you for comment... i have released it with the distribution certificate and apple approved it and now its crashing when anybody uses it by downloading it from itunes..

Answer (score 0):

Hopfully you have kept the dSym file for that particular build you submitted to iTunes.

You should then be able to open the crashlog in Xcode and have it symbolicate the crashlog lines like

```
Bagainfly 0x000020de 0x1000 + 4318
Bagainfly 0x00002074 0x1000 + 4212
```

into something meaningful in your code. Hopefully it will point you to the exact line in your app that is crashing.

Another problem is however that you are only seeing the tip of the iceberg. The crash reports available to you from Apple is heavily filtered. So if you are seeing crash reports in your developer account it means that your users are really getting hit heavy with the problem.

I can recommend a github project that will allow your users to directly send crash reports to you. This way you will get immediate notification when thigs start to go wrong and hopefully before your users start to abandon your app.
You can grab the code here:
http://github.com/TheRealKerni/CrashReporterDemo