# xcode 4.3 adhoc copy to device error

Tags: xcode4, rights, adhoc

i followed these instructions for building an adhoc version in xcode 4.0 (4.3 compilier)

- i used the distribution profile instead of dev
- added entitlements.plist

same project worked for adhoc before i upgraded to 4.3

http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

now:
project compiles finde (via archive) i can share it. 
i can push the file into itunes

BUT
i cant get the app on my device. i always get an error "invalid rights"

Maybe someone can help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the same profile for Debug and Build and Run (as debug, not release) with the target set to your Device.

Comment: i already changed every option i could find to my adhoc profile. still no luck

Comment: Where do you get the error? In the debug window or as an alert?

Comment: when i try to sync the app on the device via itunes. the error appears in a popup / alert - i could take a screenshot but its in german.

Comment: Did you register your device (device id) on iTunesConnect and download and add the files to your iTunes library?

Comment: i registered it on the provisioning portal and downloaded the new mobileprovsionining file.
like i said: it all worked fine before i upgraded to the new xcode version(4 / 4.3)

Comment: Did you configure your device in the Organizer window of XCode4?

Comment: i uploaded an image with the error. in the organizer everything seems to be fine. (no yellow allerts)

Comment: Try this link here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558642/entitlements-are-not-valid

Comment: its wired - somehow it works on "some devices". it seems to work on one of my clients devices - but on none of mine. and even only on some of my clients devices, althogh i added all devices in the adhoc profile.

Comment: Try the Apple Developer Forums

Comment: wired shit. in "share" i checkt the "identity" - i have two profiles there. also i reinstalled the profiles. crazy stuff :)