# I can't upload application to App Store

Tags: xcode, ios, app-store

I can't upload application to App Store

This is my issue:

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to build for ad-hoc distribution, see this: [entitlements are not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558642/entitlements-are-not-valid)

Comment: I trying to build for Distribution not ad-hoc distribution. My config:
 http://s3.postimage.org/67n9o4fn1/Untitled.png